# Java 8 streams - convert List of UUID to List of String considering NULL

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

- I want to set a `List<String>` to the field `selectedResources`.
- `getProtectionSet()` returns a `List<ProtectionSet>`
- ProtectionSet has a field `List<UUID> resourceIds` and this `List<UUID>` = `List<String>` I want to save in selectedResources.
- `getProtectionSet()` is a list but I want to get values from first
  element
- I don't want to have NPE exception
- when any list is empty, it makes no sense to go further.

```
private Mono<Protection> addProt(Protection protection) {
...
...
    MyClass.builder()
    .fieldA(...)
    .fieldB(...)
    .selectedResources(  //-->List<String> is expected
                       protection.getProtectionSet().stream() //List<ProtectionSet>
                                  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                  .findFirst()
                                  .map(ProtectionSet::getResourceIds) //List<UUID>
                                  .get()
                                  .map(UUID::toString)
                                  .orElse(null))
    .fieldD(...)
```

How to write my stream to avoid NPE exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though you shouldn't really face a `NullPointerException` with your current code, there are still possibilities of getting a `NoSuchElementException` for performing a `get` on `Optional` without confirming the presence.

You should use `orElse` few stages ahead as I understand the problem such that you `map` the first element found and stream only its element if available :

```
protection.getProtectionSet().stream() //List<ProtectionSet>
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .findFirst() // first 'ProtectionSet'
        .map(p -> p.getResourceIds()) // Optional<List<UUID>> from that 
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList()) // here if no such element is found
        .stream()
        .map(UUID::toString) // map in later stages
        .collect(Collectors.toList()) // collect to List<String>
```

Comment: I guess `.orElse(Collections.emptyList())` can be omitted. Calling `Optional::stream` returns an empty one if the origin is empty.

Comment: @Nikolas true, but only with Java-9+